# Can't edit class information on python3 database, NoneType object

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

That's my problem:

```
File "/home/kl33m/Download/OOP/materialListEdit.py", line 17, in getName
return self.findByCode(code).getName()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getName'
```

```
class materialListEdit(materialList,generalListEdit):
    def newRec(self, code = 0, name = "", priceforgramm = 0):
        self.appendList(material(code, name, priceforgramm))
        
    def setName(self, code, value):
        self.findByCode(code).setName(value)

    def setPriceForGramm(self, code, value):
        self.findByCode(code).setPriceForGramm(value)
```

That's problem show up one of three classes. Idk how it can work like this.

materiallist

```
def getName(self,code):return self.findByCode(code).getName()
def getPriceForGramm(self,code):return self.findByCode(code).getPriceForGramm()
```

And the some small additions:

[Error Full Name](https://wmpics.pics/edit_post.php?id=365702);

[Github All Code](https://github.com/PanyushkinOOP/oopbase)

Comment: Looks like `self.findByCode()` does not return anything - maybe it cannot find whatever you're looking for or the function does anything else. It's hard to say without the real code, really.

Comment: please provide a [mre]